# How to get colors of particular area of a BMP image in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to get the colors of the center bottom part of a BMP image. How this can be done, I need some techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Bitmap class.  It has a GetPixel() method which takes X/Y coordinates and returns the color of that pixel.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

If this isn't enough, you'll have to describe more of what you are trying to accomplish.